# How was this result: a e^(a t) Log[e] computed from D[u[t],t]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How was the result computed in Out[43]? Instead of capital E, I used lower case, but I thought the result would have been a*e^(a t) anyways. Computation at [42] has no impact. Left it there as a log.

In[41]:=u[t_] = e^(a t)

Out[41]=u[t_] = e^(a t)

In[42]:=u[4]

Out[42]=e^(4 a)

In[43]:=D[u[t], t]

Out[43]:=a e^(a t) Log[e]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D[E^(a t), t]` produces `a E^(a t)`

but you want to know why `D[e^(a t), t]` produces `a e^(a t) Log[e]`

So using `x` instead of `e` to completely avoid confusion with Euler's number, this is the step-by-step solution from Mathematica using WolframAlpha

```
WolframAlpha["D[x^(a t),t]"]
```

or using the shortcut `==` to open the WolframAlpha interpreter

[image]

If `x` were `E` then `Log[E]` would simplify to 1 and the answer would be `a E^(a t)`.

By the way, you can type in the special `e` character for Euler's number using *Esc* e e *Esc*.  It is equivalent to E.

Comment: Chris, got it. Thanks for explaining that. Now I understand what happened.